# How do I execute Guile's 'Shadow Throw'(AKA 'Invisible Throw') move?

Tags: street-fighter-ii

In *Street Fighter II* (arcade version), does anyone remember how to do what was called a 'Shadow Throw' (aka 'Invisible Throw'), with Guile? There was a certain combination of buttons and joystick movements that would set Guile into a 'frozen' state (he'd be locked into a phase of the standing roundhouse kick), where then the player could execute a secret move that would essentially throw the opponent regardless of where they were on the screen.

This was not an official move but more of a secret move that only the real die-hards knew about. This was only possible in *Street Fighter II*, not the *Champion* or *Turbo* editions.

Comment: You mean like [this movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1o6QaDNxBM)? If so then I think I remember it, but not much sure

Comment: Ahh yes there it is. I remembered it differently, but that is essentially what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging around, and found some info from [this](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Guile%27s_Invisible_Throw) site:

> To do the glitch, one must charge back then hit forward on the joystick along with the fierce and roundhouse buttons. This is a precise motion; the roundhouse must be done slightly before the fierce and should be hit slightly after moving the joystick forward. One can use the throw backwards as well by doing the same inputs, but instead hit backward on the joystick along with the fierce and roundhouse buttons in the same fashion after hitting forward.

> This glitch can be used many times in succession until the opponent is KO'ed as long as said opponent is in range. To perform repeated forward throws, hold the joystick forwards after the previous throw and press the fierce and roundhouse. To perform repeated backward throws, hold the joystick forwards after the previous throw then hit backward and press the fierce and roundhouse. If the opponent crosses Guile's body then one must switch directions.

> This glitch also has another version in which he can feint an invisible throw. To do this, perform the same inputs as normal, but this time, the fierce and roundhouse buttons must be released within 4 frames of the animation. Doing so will cause Guile to perform the throw animation, but it won't affect the opponent at all.